# Can low battery voltage cause brake noises? - 2006 Civic

Tags: battery, brakes, abs, voltage

Driving a 2006 Honda Civic, right rear brake makes a clunking noise under medium to high braking.  It sounds like the ABS but doesn't have the pedal pushing back like ABS does.  Went to my usual mechanic, they checked everything over and said it was fine.  No mechanical issues.  They didn't take the car for a drive, acted like my imagination.  Went to a 2nd mechanic who said it is low battery voltage. No posts about low voltage causing a noise. No brake or ABS lights are on.  I dislike the idea of buying a new $200 battery to fix a brake knock.  Unsure this is the real issue.  Advice welcome. Anyone have this happen?

Comment: Did you ask the 2nd mechanic to explain to you how low voltage could cause noise in the braking system ?

Comment: He said it was the ABS modulator

Comment: if your car starts the voltage is okay,get a second opinion from an other mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

If low voltage was the cause of any problems with the ABS then you would have active and/or stored DTC's in the abs module. It would likely trigger the ABS light and might also disable the abs completely while the code is active. Even then Im not sure how this could create any kind of "clunking" noise. Sounds just as likely as me telling you your tail light fluid is leaking on the caliper, causing the pads to rub.

I am also not sure, is it a 2006 or 2016?

Comment: Sry, typo.  2006.  The clunking is the ABS...maybe the modulator or just the system engaging in some way.  But it doesn't feel like ABS in the pedal and sounds differently than when it engages in snow.  I looked for leaks, nothing readily apparent.

Comment: Issue's here should store codes in abs module. Did either mechanic scan the vehicle and retrieve any codes?

Comment: They said there was a low voltage ABS code but would not tell me what it was.  Suggested they replace the battery and gave me an estimate of $275 plus tax to install it.  Neither shop giving me a good feeling.  I prefer to use my own wrench when possible, not hard to swap a battery.  I just question whether this is the issue.  Maybe I need to see a third garage and get the codes.